# How to Implement AWS cognito custom flow using triggers in user pool by .net core

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I am using AWS Cognito as the central stand-alone authorizer through all services, but I have faced with a couple of issues as below

1. no custom scope is added to access token
2. practically I can not authorize the resources on ApiGateway by using access token (*only id token works which in fact do not help us at all, we strictly need authorization part to be implemented*)
3. I am trying to use custom flow to try to add custom scopes or claims in pre-token-generation lambda, but I can not find any appropriate incoming event for the lambda or even any code sample on the net

generally, I have not got stuck in only adding scopes, any solution which helps me to implement authorization part which is ACL-like (*any user can have any access regarding some conditions or admin decides to grant/revoke specific access permissions to/from specific users*)

if nothing works for AWS Cognito I have to switch to another solution which makes me disappointed a lot from AWS Cognito, since I have found this issue reported more than 2 years ago and still not resolved!

and also a lot of time and effort will be wasted from me!

[image]